# There is an available RJ45 wall socket, without network configuration information, how do I connect to the network?

Tags: ethernet, wired-networking

In my apartment I have an RJ45 wall socket and I have permission from the landlord to use it (I've asked him). He doesn't know much about technology; so cannot provide me with the configuration information. He's mentioned several times since I rented that the building has free internet.

So is there anyway that I can go about setting up the network without any additional information?

I think the socket is active because when I connected a laptop the Ethernet port lit up.

Comment: If it has a dhcp server it should 'just work'. Without one, if its a static IP, its tricky. You could try common combinations of ip address ranges and gateways until you get one, but there's a risk of fun stuff like IP address collisions.

Comment: How do other apartments connect? There is a small chance IP address and gateway from DHCP are correct but not DNS, so please put the "ipconfig /all" + "nslookup test.de 8.8.8.8" info into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Plug the computer into the RJ45 outlet with a known good Ethernet cable. First see if Google comes up. If not, open a command prompt and type IPCONFIG.

Write down the key parts (IP Address is the most key) and then take it to the landlord.

The landlord does have a responsibility here and must get someone to set it up if he/she does not know how.

Comment: I don't think it has a dhcp server. Then how do I go about probing for available services. If it does have a dhcp server, I have no idea about what its address would be.

Comment: With wired Internet there is no configuration required. Get the IPConfig and talk to the landlord. It is very (very) unlikely the landlord would set all tenants up with static IP.  Get the IP address you have and ask the landlord

Comment: Its most likely as @John says, now that I think about it. The building complex has about 350 apartments, so it likely has dhcp. On a related note, if I had a network that didn't have dhcp and no IP, how would I know what services are there? Would scanning work? if so which address range would be scanned?

Comment: Truly you need to determine if Internet is working and get it working. If you wish to add a router and make your own network, that is easy to do but also a new question. Printing and Scanning (which I do here) is part of an added router question. First get internet working

Comment: Did you get Internet from your Apartment outlet?